# Removing emoticions in C++

Tags: c++11

I am trying to remove emoticons from a string in c++.
I have tried regex but unable to do it.

```
const std::string text = "What are  you doing today .";
const std::regex emoji("[\u1F600|U+1F604]");

std::stringstream result;
std::regex_replace(std::ostream_iterator<char>(result), text.begin(), text.end(), emoji, "");

std::cout << result.str()+"\n";
```

Comment: That's neither a `wstring`, nor a wide character literal on the right side. How have you managed to store it in the first place?

Comment: I'll bet that the emojis are UTF-8 encoded in your narrow-character string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I guess so. It should be possible to detect the leading bytes more explicitly, but simplest would be to convert it to widestring, fix it and convert it back.

Comment: That regex is anyway wrong with square brackets. Perhaps it would work with  round brackets? As it stands on  trivial reading you are looking for 3 symbols, including the `|`. In detail it is probably looking for a variety of high-bit codes ()the prefix bytes) and 3 low codes that don't make sense.

Comment: I tried your code on Visual Studio 2015 and it seems to work fine. The resultant string is free from emojis. Could you post here the output you getting?